# Execute shortcode only once in the page

Tags: shortcode

Is there a way to prevent more than one shortcode to run in the same page? If shortcode is already been executed not to run another.

```
add_shortcode('foo', 'foo_add_player');
function foo_add_player($atts){
   //do not run twice
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a flag like `$already_run` to static and give it an initial value `false`. Then check if that value is true. If not, do the one-time thing and then set `$already_run` to `true`. The next time this function is called, it will not re-assign the static property, but will instead use the value set at end of code. So it will skip second and subsequent calls.

```
function foo_add_player($atts) {
    static $already_run = false;
    if ( $already_run !== true ) {
        // do stuff here
    }
    $already_run = true;
}
```